# Rename a folder in php doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename a directory in PHP by doing this:

```
if (file_exists('img/'.$resultat['pseudo'])){
    rename("img/".$resultat['pseudo'], "img/".$newpseudo);
}
```

And before executing this code, i created the directory by doing this:

```
if (!file_exists('img/'.$_SESSION['pseudo'])){
    mkdir("img/".$_SESSION['pseudo'], 0700);
}
```

it won't rename anyhting, i don't know why

Any ideas ?

Comment: errors? warnings? notice?

Comment: there's nothing printed in the html file

Comment: put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors,' true);` on top of the page please

Comment: are you sure that file_exists('img/'.$resultat['pseudo']) is evaluated to true ?

Comment: Yes, i printed something in the if condition

Comment: What is `$newpseudo`?

Comment: thank you Federico it allowed me to see that most of the time     $resultat['pseudo'] doesn't exist.